# Parse JSON in Java

Tags: java, json

I am currently working with Java, reading JSON response from a webservice.
Till now I have been parsing JSON for a path known in advance. So I am able to make objects and arrays depending on situation.

```
String jsonText = readAll(br);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
JSONObject resp = json.getJSONObject("Response");
```

But now I have a problem. I have to ask user to provide me a path and I have to get the value at that path in JSON response. Path could be incorrect - return error in that case.

Kind of like XPath in XML. Do we have something similar in JSON?

Path could for example look like:
/Response/VehicleSearch/Vehicles/Vehicle[2]/Features/Feature[7]/ID

Please excuse me if its a stupid question. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using GSON , a google library for dealing with JSON

Comment: For a solution with Gson, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658124/finding-deeply-nested-key-value-in-json

Comment: You have the JSON decomposed into a tree structure.  You access that with a "path" just as you'd access the XML, though you may have to step through the branches yourself vs using a path notation.

Comment: (This is not a "stupid" question, but you've obviously not put much effort into research.)

Comment: I did look up and found json-path. 
I am currently playing with it and having some problem for which I posted another question.

I am kind of on a short leash with this one hence posted the question right off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `JSON` equivalent of `XPATH for XML` you can use [**`JsonPath`**](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)

As per docs:

> `JsonPath` is to `JSON` what `XPATH` is to `XML`, a simple way to extract
>   parts of a given document. `JsonPath` is available in many programming
>   languages such as `Javascript`, `Python` and `PHP`. **Now also in Java!**

Comment: Nice. I didn't know this one but it's surely quite handy for lots of occasions.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava for pointing to jsonpath.

I am currently trying to play with jsonpath but having some problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539862/parse-json-using-jsonpath-in-java.

Comment: Sorry just got back and realized you've resolved the problem on other thread.