# check if multiple keys are present in a JSON String - Java

Tags: java, json, validation, key, schema

I have a  complicated JSON String (Array/Object) and I have to check whether it contains some keys.Its basically a validation for the JSON String I got.

eg

```
inputJson:{
    a:[
        {
            key1:val1,
            key2:val2
        },{
            key1:val1,
            key2:val2
        },
    ],
    b:
    c:{
        key3:val3,
        key4:val4
    }
}
```

and I have to verify if the JSON contains `a`, `c` , `c.key4` ,`a[*].key1`. If the key is present,its value shouldnt be null.

I have seen many other discussions here , but either its not supporting array inside object or its using heavy libraries for JSON Validation. What I am looking for is a simple library or method which just checks if the keys are present in a JSON String.

Please give me pointers on how to do this.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by *heavy* libraries?

Comment: This may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658124/finding-deeply-nested-key-value-in-json

Comment: @Andremoniy Heavy libraries in the sense which validate json keys and values, what I require is simple key validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I wrote the code for my requirement.

```
public Object parseJsonForKey(String key,JSONObject jsonObject) throws DigitalSelfException{
          try {
            String[] keyPathArray = key.split("\\.");
            System.out.println("Array length :" + keyPathArray.length);
            if (keyPathArray.length == 1) {
                if (jsonObject.containsKey(key)) {
                    return jsonObject.get(key);
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            JSONObject tempObj = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray tempArray = new JSONArray();
            if (jsonObject.get(keyPathArray[0]) instanceof JSONObject) {
                tempObj = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get(keyPathArray[0]);
            } else if (jsonObject.get(keyPathArray[0]) instanceof JSONArray) {
                tempArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get(keyPathArray[0]);
                tempObj = (JSONObject) tempArray.get(0);
            }
            System.out.println(tempObj.toString());
            for (int i = 1; i < keyPathArray.length - 1; i++) {
                if (tempObj.containsKey(keyPathArray[i])) {
                    if (tempObj.get(keyPathArray[i]) instanceof JSONObject) {
                        tempObj = (JSONObject) tempObj.get(keyPathArray[i]);
                    } else if (tempObj.get(keyPathArray[i]) instanceof JSONArray) {
                        tempArray = (JSONArray) tempObj.get(keyPathArray[i]);
                        tempObj = (JSONObject) tempArray.get(0);
                    }                   
                    System.out.println(tempObj.toString());
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            if (tempObj.containsKey(keyPathArray[keyPathArray.length - 1])) {
               return tempObj.get(keyPathArray[keyPathArray.length - 1]);
            } else {
                return null;
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // throw Exception
        }
```

and I call the above function as

```
for (String key : mandatoryKeys) {
                if(ValidatorUtil.parseJsonForKey(key,jsonObject)==null){                   
                    return false;
                }                         
            }
```

So if the value is null , it means the key is not present. Otherwise it contains the value for the key.

mandatoryKeys example :["a","c","c.key4","a.key1"]

I used org.simple.json library.

This method works fine for my requirement.